# DataGridView C# search gives null

Tags: c#, datagridview, null

I wanted to create a simple program that looks trough each row of a dataGridView on a specific cell.
I got it to work but if the string that I search for isn't found it gives back null. Which screws it up. Here is the code:

```
string targetSearch = textBox2.Text;

dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Equals(targetSearch))
    {
        row.Selected = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the DGV is set to `AllowUserToAddRows` you are looping thru one too many rows.

Comment: What value should it have if not `null`?

Comment: Please explain what each use of “it” in your question refers to.

Comment: Set AllowUsersToAddRows to False.

Comment: BTW, sorry if my question wasn't clear enough! But as someone fixed it already it shouldn't matter to mutch, thanks either way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***These solutions works for me.*** 
**Sample UI** 
[image]

**Validate if the value is null.**

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string targetSearch = txtSearch.Text.Trim();

   dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
   foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
      if (row.cells[0].value == null)
          continue;
      if(row.cells[0].value.Tostring().Trim().Equals(targetSearch)) {
          row.Selected = true;
          break;
       }
   }
}
```

**Handle the NullReference Exception**

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string targetSearch = txtSearch.Text.Trim();
     dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;

            try
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Equals(targetSearch))
                    {
                        row.Selected = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException ex) {   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are converting null value to string, which gives `System.NullReferenceException`.

```
string targetSearch = textBox2.Text;

dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells[0].Value == null) continue; //add this 
    if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Equals(targetSearch))
    {
        row.Selected = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can try:

1. Either Set "AllowUserstoAddRows" to False

or

2. Put the foreach loop in a  Try catch block in order to handle the NullReference exception